# .htaccess and 500 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

we are using a wordpress multisite with 40 or so subdomains all with their own mapping. After adding two more sites a 500 error appears on a particular page for all of the subdomains. We also can't add anymore pages without the error occuring. The main site in which the subdomains are part of is treragent.co.uk.

Having spoken to the hosts of our dedicated server (webfusion) they have said that it is an .htaccess error. I am familiar with .htaccess but as all the sites rank quite well we don't want them to fall. This is what our code is at the moment:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newtest4/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /newtest4/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newtest4/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /newtest4/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is the error it throws up:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: What does your apache error logs say?

Comment: This happens if you have a .htaccess mistake that correct. Buts perhaps there is an error in your vhost config.

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: If this file is located in the root, remove the `newtest4/` so you have `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Why is your .htaccess showing duplicate code block?

Comment: Thank you. What would we do about the rewrite rule?? I didn't write it. A previous IT techie wrote it